# Mapping a range of values to a single value

Tags: c++, algorithms

So I have this problem where a specific `ValuesA` enum value is to be mapped to a respective `ValuesB` enum value, The trick is there can be multiple `ValuesA` mapping to a single `ValuesB` enum.

So for the following example:

- I have randomly chosen a max range of 3 `ValuesA` enum values mapping to a single `ValuesB` enum value.
- Each set of values are 'categorized' under a `BASE_i` value
- Each range of values map to a single `ValuesB` value

  - `ValuesA`[0x01, 0x03]   map to `ValuesB::ONE` [0x01]
  - `ValuesA` [0x04, 0x06] map to `ValuesB::TWO` [0x02]
- Each `BASE_x` values may not have ALL the values that could be mapped to a said `ValueB`. For instance in this example:

  - `BASE_0` only contains `BASE_0_TEN` that maps to `ValueB::FOUR` where `BASE_1` doesn't contain any such value.
  - `BASE_0` doesn't contain any values that map to `ValuesB::THREE` where `BASE_1` contains values that map to `ValuesB::THREE`

```
enum class ValuesA : uint32_t
{
    BASE_0 = 0x00'00'00'00,
    
    // < maps to ValuesB::ONE -> 0x01 >
    BASE_0_ONE    = 0x00'00'00'01,
    BASE_0_TWO    = 0x00'00'00'02,
    BASE_0_THREE  = 0x00'00'00'03,
    // !!! WHAT if in the future there would be a NEW BASE_0 value here? !!!
    
    // < maps to ValuesB::TWO -> 0x02 >
    BASE_0_FOUR   = 0x00'00'00'04,
    BASE_0_FIVE   = 0x00'00'00'05,
    BASE_0_SIX    = 0x00'00'00'06,
    
    /*
        < no values that map to ValuesB::THREE -> 0x03 >
        BASE_0_SEVEN = 0x00'00'00'07
        BASE_0_EIGHT = 0x00'00'00'08
        BASE_0_NINE  = 0x00'00'00'09
    */
    
    
    // < only one value maps to ValuesB::FOUR -> 0x04 >
    BASE_0_TEN  = 0x00'00'00'0A,
    
    /*
        < no values >
        MAP_0_ELEVEN  = 0x00'00'00'0B  
        MAP_0_TWELVE  = 0x00'00'00'0C
    */
    
    
    
    
    BASE_1 = 0x00'01'00'00,
    
    // < maps to ValuesB::ONE -> 0x01 >
    BASE_1_ONE   = 0x00'01'00'01,
    BASE_1_TWO   = 0x00'01'00'02,
    BASE_1_THREE = 0x00'01'00'03,
    
    /*
        < no values that map to ValuesB::TWO -> 0x02 >
        BASE_1_FOUR   = 0x00'00'00'04,
        BASE_1_FIVE   = 0x00'00'00'05,
        BASE_1_SIX    = 0x00'00'00'06,
    */
    
    // maps to ValuesB::THREE -> 0x03
    BASE_1_SEVEN  = 0x00'01'00'07,
    BASE_1_EIGHT  = 0x00'01'00'08,
    BASE_1_NINE   = 0x00'01'00'09,
};

enum class ValuesB : uint16_t
{
    ONE   = 1,
    TWO   = 2,
    THREE = 3,
    FOUR  = 4
};
```

---

### Approaches

1. Perhaps one easy a way to go about is to create a map with `ValuesB` as a key and `ValuesA` as values. As we know the mapping at compile time, we can go about populating the map.

```
std::unordered_map<ValuesB, std::vector<ValuesA>> mapValuesBToValuesA;
```

2. A rather "efficient" approach that doesn't require hashing could include:

   - get the last 16 bits of `ValuesA` and get the `ValuesB` based on the hardcoded range checks

```
ValuesB MapValueAToValueB(ValuesA valueA)
{
    /*
        [0x01, 0x03] -> [0x01]
        [0x04, 0x06] -> [0x02],
    */
    uint16_t value = static_cast<uint32_t>(valueA) & 0xFFFF;
    
    if (value >= 0x01 && value <= 0x03)
    {
        return ValuesB::ONE; 
    }

    if (value >= 0x04 && value <= 0x06)
    {
        return ValuesB::TWO; 
    }
    // ...
}
```

---

### ISSUE

I am inclined towards the Approach 2 but only if it's a feasible one. Following are the shortcomings I see and whether we can overcome it:

1. Range to separate out the what `ValueB` would be mapped to:

   - For this example I randomly selected 3 as a MAX range to identify what `ValuesB` would be mapped to but in the production, you probably don't want to be in a situation where you feel the need to make `ValuesA:: BASE_0_FOUR` that maps to `ValuesB::ONE` as well.

---

### Question

1. Can Approach 2 be made more scalable? If so, what would you do differently based on what's described above?

Hopefully I'm not overthinking it

Comment: Your map approach seems "reversed", a `map<ValueA, ValueB>` (ordered or not) is what corresponds to what you do in 2). (And is IMO much better than 2.)

Comment: Why not just write a function with a switch/case? You can have multiple case labels that return the same ValueB. I think you might be overcomplicating this by thinking in terms of "ranges".

Comment: @Mat the order won't matter - the idea would really be to retrieve the key (`ValueB`) out of a value (`ValueA`) hence the unordered_map

Comment: Maps aren't bidirectional (at least not the ones in the standard library). You can't look up based on the value.

Comment: @amon switch/case alone won't work; the enum values have to align with what they'd map to a single `ValueB`. You can have [0, 3] map to [1] but what in the future you want to have [0, 4] map to [1] instead. What happens to original `ValueA` values that were categorized from `[4, 6]`, and so on...

Comment: @Mat sure but there are ways to get the key from the value :)

Answer (score 3):

By trying to encode mapping information into the representation of ValueA, you are just needlessly complicating stuff for yourself. Just write ValueA as you would if there was no mapping concern to ValueB and let the compiler optimize the mapping logic.

For example:

```
enum ValueA {
  FOO,
  BAR, 
  BAZ, 
  QUUX,
  FOOBAR
};

enum ValueB {
  ONE = 1,
  TWO,
  THREE,
};

ValueB mapValueAToValueB(ValueA src)
{
  switch (src)
  {
  case FOO:
  case BAR:
  case FOOBAR:
    return ONE;
  case BAZ:
  case QUUX:
    return THREE;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works but ideally I was mainly looking for something that only involves modifying `ValueA` enum class rather than modifying the map function.

Answer (score 0):

The most critical question to consider is whether the mapping to B is inherently dependent on the value of the instance of A being mapped.

If there is a clear relationship between the two, you can opt for an algorithm or heuristic to implement the mapping. On the other hand, if the mapping is unrelated to the numeric value of A, you'll need a mechanism to check each value, such as a mapping table or using switch/ifs.

The problem with the example you provide, is that its an abstract example, which obscures  the fundamental design question.

The key aspect to understand here is the nature of the problem domain and to what extent the mapping is influenced by the value. If the mapping is indeed a function of the value, it is appropriate to utilize it. However, if it's not a function, using a function would be an assumption waiting for a bug that would eventual expose it. Therefore, a thorough analysis of the relationship between A and B is critical for a reliable and robust implementation.

Answer (score -1):

> A Turing machine is a mathematical model of computation describing an abstract machine that manipulates symbols on a strip of tape according to a table of rules. Despite the model's simplicity, it is capable of implementing any computer algorithm.

Definition from the Wikipedia page.

To summarise the plenty of Turing machine implementations available on the internet it's a tremendous work. What it's feasible instead is to describe the Turing machine to reveal it's suitable to the discussed topic that is about source values routed to destination values. The source values are described by `ValuesA` enum, the destination values are described by `ValuesB` enum and the question is: "who describes the routes". There could be a map with keys of type `ValuesA` and values of type `ValuesB`, there could be a chain of responsibility with each strategy exposing couple of methods one to test whether the source value is supported and one to route the source value to the destination value (approach 2 without the issue? probably), to go wild the routing could be retrieved from an external storage - from a database, from a file system, from a web service.

Comment: Why do you start talking about Turing machines?